# What determines the state variables we use to express thermodynamic quantities?

Tags: thermodynamics

In my thermodynamics class, often we will need to express some differential quantity (e.g. internal energy) as a function of other state variables. Like,
$$
dU = \left(\frac{\partial U}{\partial T}\right)_V dT + \left(\frac{\partial U}{\partial V}\right)_T dV
$$
However, occasionally my professor will write something along the lines of
$$
dU = \left(\frac{\partial U}{\partial T}\right)_P dT + \left(\frac{\partial U}{\partial P}\right)_T dP
$$
Both of these seem to be correct descriptions of $dU$, despite one being in terms of $T$ and $V$ and the other being in terms of $T$ and $P$.

Is this because $T$ and $P$ constrain $V$? Is this always the case? When I've looked elsewhere for an answer I found explanations in terms of Legendre transformations of natural variables? We have not covered this yet, so I was wondering if there was a simpler explanation that I have overlooked.

Comment: You need a 3rd variable, often denoted by $N$ the number of molecules and is equivalent to the mass of the thermodynamic body, chemists like to think in gram-moles. Otherwise, $T,p$ together would not determine the volume; after all, any macroscopic part within the system has the same $T,p$ parameters. The total internal energy is usually proportional to mass so that mass specific energy, that is per unit mass, can be determined by $T,p$ most of the time.